# What kind of push notification approach is appropriate to use for Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a push message system inside my application and have been searching for a push service in Android.

I found several different approaches, and the one that caught my eye was Google's GCM, but it seems it's not available for 2.3.3, and I would need to upgrade to API level 20. This means loosing a huge amount of users just because Google doesn't want to support historic versions of Android.

Can anyone tell me what the best approach is for implementing push notifications in 2.3.3 or above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can and probably should use GCM. It's available for Android 2.2+ (API level 8+).
2. There is not yet such a thing as API level 20 -- requiring it certainly would cut out a lot of Android users!
3. The documentation is quite thorough, and it is available here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: I can't install it from android-sdk!!! I on;y installed API level 10 and now in extra tree I can't see a sign of GCM!

Comment: @austin It's not part of the SDK. You really should check out the docs that both Rawkode and I pointed you at.

Comment: I read the google doc it said ought to install it from SDK!!! read it : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#libs

Comment: @austinpowers Sorry, I hadn't noticed that they're recommending that now. I also understand where you got your "20" from -- you need to upgrade your Android SDK *tools* to *revision* 20. Then you'll see the helper libraries they're talking about. Doing this doesn't affect the API level you build for or the devices your app can run on, it just upgrades your tools for working with the Anroid SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Messaging is available from API level 8 (Android 2.2)

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I implemented in Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is a bad recommendation -- C2DM has been deprecated in favor of GCM.

Comment: and they are not getting new user anymore